# Need to prevent a package from being installed

Tags: apt

I have a package I do not want to be installed even if another needs it.

Is there any way to "blacklist" a package from being installed even as a dependency of another?

Can I overcome the fact that it is a dependency and still be able to upgrade my system?

I am thinking in particular about the messaging indicator from Unity. If I remove it and add Unity again for some reason, I dont want the applet installed again. How can I prevent it from being installed? (or the global menu, java versions removing my custom installed one, etc... you get the idea).

Comment: Is it available by apt-get command?

Comment: Yes, I am talking about `apt` as tagged on the question.

Comment: In my case I installed texlive from the TUG website so I would like to block all texlive related packages from Ubuntu.

Comment: bruno: http://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package  ;) see AbrahamVanHelpsing´s answer.

Answer (score 39):

- Is there any way to "blacklist" a package from being installed even as a dependency of another?

To prevent `apt` from installing a package `foo`, add a stanza for that package to the file /etc/apt/preferences which looks like the following.

```
Package: foo
Pin: release *
Pin-Priority: -1
```

This will prevent apt from installing foo and will also prevent apt from installing anything that Depends on foo.

The next closest thing I can think of is to put a *hold* on foo at its current version which prevents foo from being upgraded (unless dpkg is given the `--force-hold` option or unless apt overrides the hold). To put a hold on package foo, do the following.

```
echo foo hold | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

- Can I overcome the fact that it is a dependency and still be able to upgrade my system?

You can install individual packages despite dependency violations using `dpkg --force-depends`. You won't be able to use `apt` to do this unless you `apt-get source` the package that Depends on foo and rebuild it without the dependency on foo.

Comment: Thanks, I guess this is as good as it gets... if I hold the package `texlive-base` and try to install `latexmk` I get `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 latexmk : Depends: texlive-latex-base but it is not going to be installed` which is of course what I want. 
But if I hold `latexmk` and do `sudo apt-get install latexmk` I will get `The following held packages will be changed:
  latexmk`, as it turns out this actually [removes the hold](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto#Removing_a_Hold) (well it least I get a warning).

Comment: In an edit I just explained another way of preventing the installation of a package, using a stanza in `/etc/apt/preferences`. This has no effect on `dpkg`, of course. And it is still the case that if you blacklist a package you won't be able to use `apt` to install anything that Depends on it.

Comment: In 16.04, I have only /etc/apt/preferences.d with nothing inside. What do I do? Or, should I create an /etc/apt/preferences file and it will read it?

Comment: How does the blacklisting via the `preferences` file works?

Comment: Does not work if anoither package provides the package you had marked as hold. Example with `sudo`,  it will install `sudo-ldap` , because it provides `sudo`...

Answer (score 2):

If a package needs (depends on) another package, then it should not work properly without it. If it can, it is a bug, it should be a recommend and not a depend.

To avoid to install a dependency:

1. download the required packages:

   ```
   sudo apt-get --download-only install pkg-name
   ```
2. remove unwanted packages

   ```
   sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archive/bad-pkg_*.deb
   ```
3. install all other packages

   ```
   sudo apt-get --no-download --ignore-missing install pkg-name
   ```

On the other side, to install a package without recommends:

```
sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install pkg-name
```

Comment: @BrunoPereira: see updated answer.

Comment: @BrunoPereira: I would like to have some feedback from you.

Comment: When you lock a package version does also lock a non installed package? I think (I'm sure) your solution would work but would really not rather use since in a update example it would still install the package, no?

Comment: Yes, in a next install `apt` would try to resore what it think is missing.