# How To dist-upgrade Without Upgrading Linux Kernel?

Tags: apt, upgrade, kernel

I am using Linux Kernel 3.19-RC5 with Oibaf graphics stack on Ubuntu Gnome and I am currently very happy with this setup. However, there is Linux Kernel 3.13.0-44 & few other packages available for `dist-upgrade`.

I would like to know :

1. Is it okay if I use `dist-upgrade` & install Linux kernel 3.13.0-44 ? I
   want to keep using 3.19-rc5 with oibaf stack and I don't want my X
   to break.
2. Is there any alternate way to do dist-upgrade by blacklisting Linux
   kernel packages ?

Comment: Already answered here.http://askubuntu.com/questions/178324/how-to-skip-kernel-update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you pull in new kernel versions is that you have the shell package `linux-image-generic` installed, which does not contain the kernel image itself but at any given time depends on the most recently released kernel package.  This is why you get a new kernel version installed even though its package name is different, containing the version number.

If you never want to automatically get a new kernel version, you can remove this shell package, ensuring that the package containing the actual kernel image is not removed along with it.

Or, if you normally do want to install new versions but you just want to temporarily avoid one particular version, you can use pinning, to tell dpkg/APT specifically to avoid a certain package, or a certain version of a package.

Pinning info: [Need to prevent a package from being installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99081/need-to-prevent-a-package-from-being-installed)